# Ruby array of hash. group_by and modify in one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, enumerable

I have an array of hashes, something like

```
[ {:type=>"Meat", :name=>"one"}, 
  {:type=>"Meat", :name=>"two"}, 
  {:type=>"Fruit", :name=>"four"} ]
```

and I want to convert it to this

```
{ "Meat" => ["one", "two"], "Fruit" => ["Four"]}
```

I tried `group_by` but then i got this

```
{ "Meat" => [{:type=>"Meat", :name=>"one"}, {:type=>"Meat", :name=>"two"}],
  "Fruit" => [{:type=>"Fruit", :name=>"four"}] }
```

and then I can't modify it to leave just the name and not the full hash. I need to do this in one line because is for a `grouped_options_for_select` on a Rails form.

Comment: There's an [`option_groups_from_collection_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-option_groups_from_collection_for_select) helper.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
array.group_by{|h| h[:type]}.each{|_, v| v.replace(v.map{|h| h[:name]})}
# => {"Meat"=>["one", "two"], "Fruit"=>["four"]}
```

Following steenslag's suggestion:

```
array.group_by{|h| h[:type]}.each{|_, v| v.map!{|h| h[:name]}}
# => {"Meat"=>["one", "two"], "Fruit"=>["four"]}
```

Comment: The last block can be written as `{|_, v| v.map!{|h| h[:name]}}`

Comment: @steenslag Thanks. I forgot about it.

Comment: ...or `each_value...`, and don't see why the `!`.

Comment: `.each_value {|v| v.map!{|h| h[:name]}}` works, but I see `!` is needed.

Answer (score 16):

In a single iteration over initial array:

```
arry.inject(Hash.new([])) { |h, a| h[a[:type]] += [a[:name]]; h }
```

Comment: Nice! (But your preamble sounds like a drum roll.  :-) )

Comment: Your answer has given me greater insight into the coolness of `inject`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using ActiveSuport's [`Hash#transform_values`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values):

```
array.group_by{ |h| h[:type] }.transform_values{ |hs| hs.map{ |h| h[:name] } }
#=> {"Meat"=>["one", "two"], "Fruit"=>["four"]}
```

Comment: `transform_values` is now part of Ruby itself (since 2.4, I think).

Answer (score 2):

```
array = [{:type=>"Meat", :name=>"one"}, {:type=>"Meat", :name=>"two"}, {:type=>"Fruit", :name=>"four"}]
array.inject({}) {|memo, value| (memo[value[:type]] ||= []) << value[:name]; memo}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do as below :

```
hsh =[{:type=>"Meat", :name=>"one"}, {:type=>"Meat", :name=>"two"}, {:type=>"Fruit", :name=>"four"}]
p Hash[hsh.group_by{|h| h[:type] }.map{|k,v| [k,v.map{|h|h[:name]}]}]

# >> {"Meat"=>["one", "two"], "Fruit"=>["four"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

[@ArupRakshit answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18921143/4352306), slightly modified (the function has been added for sake of clarity in the final example):

```
def group(list, by, at)
  list.group_by { |h| h[by] }.map { |k,v| [ k , v.map {|h| h[at]} ] }.to_h
end

sample =[
  {:type=>"Meat",  :name=>"one",  :size=>"big"   },
  {:type=>"Meat",  :name=>"two",  :size=>"small" },
  {:type=>"Fruit", :name=>"four", :size=>"small" }
]

group(sample, :type, :name) # => {"Meat"=>["one", "two"], "Fruit"=>["four"]}
group(sample, :size, :name) # => {"big"=>["one"], "small"=>["two", "four"]}
```

Please, notice that, although not mentioned in the question, you may want to preserve the original `sample` as it is. Some answers kept provision on this, others not as.

After grouping (`list.group_by {...}`) the part that does the transformation (without modifying the original sample's values) is:

```
.map { |k,v| [ k , v.map {|h| h[at]} ] }.to_h
```

Some **hints**:

1. iterating the pairs of the `Hash` of groups (first `map`), where
2. for each iteration, we receive `|group_key, array]` and return an `Array` of `[group_key, new_array]` (outer `block`),
3. and finally `to_h` transforms the `Array of Array`s into the `Hash` (this `[[gk1,arr1],[gk2,arr2]...]` into this `{ gk1 => arr1, gk2 => arr2, ...}`)

There is one missing step not explained at step (2) above. `new_array` is made by `v.map {|h| h[at]}`, which justs casts the value `at` of each original `Hash` (`h`) element of the `array` (so we move from `Array of Hash`es to an `Array` of elements).

Hope that helps others to understand the example.