# Render JSON and pair records from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am working with rails API , and I want to render JSON file but with specific way.
I have a model with named Store, and in this model, i have records like State and City. My problem is that I want render JSON to looks like this:

```
{ 
"Arizona": [
      "Phoenix",
      "Tucson"
    ],
    "California": [
      "Anaheim",
      "Los Angeles",
      "San Diego",
      "San Francisco"
    ],
    "Colorado": [
      "Denver"
    ],
}
```

I may have in model many records with the name Colorado or with the name California, but every California record have its own city name, for example:

this is my model

```
|  state   |   city   |
-----------------------
|California| Anaheim  |
|Colorado  | Denver   |
|California| San Diego|
```

and so on ..

so I want to pair every city that belongs to the unique state, so my JSON would show only one time the State name .

any suggestion?

Comment: See this for using jbuilder to build json output. http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder?view=asciicast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Model.select(:state, :city).group{|add| address.state}
```

This will return:

> {"California" => [ModelObject2, ModelObject2 ], "Colarado" =>
>   [ModelObject1]}

Now we need to replace second object part with the city name so loop over the second part and get city from that object and then `to_json` to convert into json object.

```
Model.select(:state, :city).group{|add| address.state}.each{|_, v| v.replace(v.map {|add| add.city})}.to_json
```

Hope this will help you!!

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920877/ruby-array-of-hash-group-by-and-modify-in-one-line)

Comment: Thank you. this was exactly what i need!